# Syntax to pass argument to unordered_set hash function in c++

Tags: c++, syntax, clang++, unordered-set

I have created a hasher class for a custom type I'm using, but it has a constructor that takes an argument. I can't figure out the syntax to use this in an unordered_set.

```
class Hasher {
    unsigned arg;
public:
    Hasher(unsigned a) : arg(a) {}
    size_t operator()(const MyType& t) const {
        return calculate_hash(arg, t);
    }
}

int main() {
    unordered_set<MyType, Hasher(2)> myset; // compilation error
}
```

The error message:

```
In file included from Tetrahedron.cc:5:
./Triangulation.h:52:29: error: template argument for template type parameter must be a type
       unordered_set<TetraFace,FaceHasher(2)> faces2;
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.3.1/../../../../include/c++/6.3.1/bits/unordered_set.h:90:11: note: template parameter is declared here
       class _Hash = hash<_Value>,
             ^
```

I also tried

```
unordered_set<MyType, Hasher> myset(Hasher(2));
```

but I still get an error:

```
In file included from Tetrahedron.cc:5:
./Triangulation.h:52:59: error: expected ')'
    unordered_set<TetraFace,FaceHasher> faces2(FaceHasher(2));
                                                          ^
./Triangulation.h:52:58: note: to match this '('
unordered_set<TetraFace,FaceHasher> faces2(FaceHasher(2));
                                                     ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting a compile error there because you're trying to pass an object (i.e. instance) of type Hasher as a template argument.

Like your error describes: `template argument for template type parameter must be a type`

It's expecting a type, and you're passing in a value.

Parameterize the arg at the type level.

```
template<unsigned A>
class Hasher {
    unsigned arg = A;
public:
    size_t operator()(const int& t) const {
        std::cout << arg << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::unordered_set<int, Hasher<2>> myset;
    myset.insert(5); // prints 2

    std::unordered_set<int, Hasher<3>> myset2;
    myset2.insert(3); // prints 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to construct a [`std::unorderd_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) with just the hash object.  [All of the constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/unordered_set) that take the hash object have a parameter before it for `bucket_count`.  You would need to specify the value for it like

```
unordered_set<MyType, Hasher> myset(some_bucket_count_value, Hasher(2));
```

If you do not want to do that then you have to make `Hasher` default constructable.

Also not that

```
return calculate_hash(arg);
```

Is not going to work as you will always hash `arg` no matter what `MyType` you pass.  You need to be hashing the `MyType` object for the `std::unordered_set` to really work.

Comment: Yes, calculate_hash was just an example to show that I need to use arg. Just to make sure, you said unordered_map, but the same goes for unordered_set, right?

Comment: Also, if I specify an initial bucket count, does c++ handle changing it when necessary, or do I have to do that myself too?

Comment: @devil0150 Oops.  It is the same for a `set`.  Just updated the answer.

Comment: The bucket count is just the minimum number of buckets. It will make more if needed.